# WebView shows the web page differently than a browser (JavaScript is enabled)

Tags: android, webview, particles

I would like to use a webpage as background in an Android application, but it looks completely different compared to a normal browser.

*The page I want to use: https://informatika.thekingsteam.tk/particle.html*

**WebView code:**

```
WebView ww = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.ww);
        ww.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        ww.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ww.loadUrl("https://informatika.thekingsteam.tk/particle.html");
```

**Why does it look different in the app than in a browser?**

**Pictures:**

Screenshot from the Browser:

[image: From browser]

Screenshot from the application

[image: From the application]